# Django: Check user name from two different models

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models: Faculty and Student. Both have a username and password.
I want to check if the username and password input provided is present in either of them. In the view, I can do a simple check on one model like this:

```
try:
    user = Student.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    error_message = "**Incorrect login. Please try again."
    context = {'error_message' : error_message}
    return render_to_response('myapp/login.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Can you point out how to do the same for both Faculty and Student at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably just to try the second query if the first fails:

```
context = {}
try:
    user = Student.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
except Student.DoesNotExist:
    try:
        user = Faculty.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
    except Faculty.DoesNotExist:
        error_message = "**Incorrect login. Please try again."
        context['error_message'] = error_message

# rest of your view here

return render_to_response('myapp/login.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

By the way, you can save yourself some effort if you use django.shortcuts.render instead of `render_to_response`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

...

return render(request, 'myapp/login.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest, you should use [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#s-substituting-a-custom-user-model) to join your models and [classic django auth utils](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests).